# android emulator using nodejs json

Tags: android, node.js

**I am trying to retrive JSON and display it on android view locally on my emulator**

- I used an online JSON link `http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/`

piece of code :: `private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";`

- i did get the correct output on my android device
- Now i am running a nodeJS on my localpc and it is running on port
  9000

piece of code now is changed to :: `private static String url = "http://127.0.0.1:9000/";`

but when i use this json the app crashes in emulator ..... any ideas on why it is crashing ... the other part of code why i have not given because it works perfectly fine. some ambiguiuity in displaying url wrt to nodejs

**AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java**

```
package net.niceandroid.jsonparsing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://127.0.0.1:9000/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id){
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });



    }

}
```

parser is :: **JSONParser.java**

```
package net.niceandroid.jsonparsing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**NODE program is ::**

```
   var http = require('http');
    var serv = http.createServer(function(req,res){
        var data = {
        "contacts": [
            {
                    "id": "c200",
                    "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                    "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c201",
                    "name": "Johnny Depp",
                    "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c202",
                    "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                    "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c203",
                    "name": "John Wayne",
                    "email": "john_wayne@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c204",
                    "name": "Angelina Jolie",
                    "email": "angelina_jolie@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "female",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c205",
                    "name": "Dido",
                    "email": "dido@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "female",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c206",
                    "name": "Adele",
                    "email": "adele@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "female",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c207",
                    "name": "Hugh Jackman",
                    "email": "hugh_jackman@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c208",
                    "name": "Will Smith",
                    "email": "will_smith@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c209",
                    "name": "Clint Eastwood",
                    "email": "clint_eastwood@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c2010",
                    "name": "Barack Obama",
                    "email": "barack_obama@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c2011",
                    "name": "Kate Winslet",
                    "email": "kate_winslet@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "female",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c2012",
                    "name": "Eminem",
                    "email": "eminem@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            }
        ]
    };

    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    }).listen(9000);
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:9000/");
```

Comment: Add what you have tried so far.It will be helpful while answering.

Comment: I'm assuming you put /contacts/ onto the end of the url? What does logcat say?

Comment: I have added the code ... @ iaindownie ..... i have not put /contacts/ at the end during node execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 192.168.[0|1].x or real ip address instead of 127.0.0.1 in your android codes.

Comment: i tried with 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 ...... but no changes emulator goes to idle state then again dosen't respond

Comment: 192.168.[0|1].x means your nodejs server listening ip address,not random one like what you have tried,i assume that,since you let me think you have tried with several ip and you didnt get what is your ip.. use browser visit http://192.168.x.x:9000 should see your json data displaying. so just try `ipconfig` in windows or `ifconfig` in linux like os to get your local network ip .:)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions...... in my nodejs i am using 9000 port so i have used the URL 192.168.0.2:9000 .... i double checked with ipconfig ... what is worring is .... my android code works when i use the example url from net to fetch JSON but it fails in case of NODEJS :(

Comment: Strange thing,so you sure you have started your nodejs server with `node` command in os command line?

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the localhost or 127.0.0.1:9000. it doesn't return anything .Use express and create Rest Services 
[Rest Services Node.js](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/) and u can use

```
URL url = new URL("Rest Service link");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();
```

this will return string pass this string to your json parser

Comment: ok just for my knowledge i only need to use http::/127.0.0.1/9000 as the string in android code nothing else ? if i run the node server on that port locally

Comment: i think so i have lost the code else i would have shared :( try http://localhost:3000/wines or  http::/127.0.0.1/9000/wines